# Click on selected SELECT option, goes to value

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

I'm using a SELECT as a main menu. There are several options, fx. "My Profile". If I go to "My Profile" and continue further down the site tree, the menu is still present and shows "My Profile" eventhough the accual page is "My Profile > Edit Profile > E-mail settings".

If I, on "E-mail settings" or other pages here under, want to go to "My Profile" I cant. Because the option has already been selected.

```
//DropdownMenu controller
    $('select.dropdownMenu').change(function() {
        //alert('url = ' + this.value );
        window.location.href = this.value;
    });
```

The above code, only works on change. So I can't select the selected option. I want to.

How can I fix this? jQuery? Do you know?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like the default option of the select to be the page you are currently on? If so, how are your pages being served - through a CMS or statically?

Comment: No. The system selects the correct option. I want to go to the value, eventhough I click on a selected option (which you can't). See my updated code.

Comment: How about adding a `-Choose a Page-` option?

Comment: if the system selects the correct option it should be selected? Are you sure you're setting the `selected` attribute for the  `option` element properly?

Comment: please paste your code in jsfiddle.net and explain in details.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how.

```
    //DropdownMenu controller

    $('select.dropdownMenu option').click(function() {
        window.location.href = this.value;
    });
```

Comment: It will not work on cross browser basis on my chrome it wont work,

Comment: I agree with Val, everytime you click the select box, the click event will fire, and you won't be able to select the other options.

Comment: I dont understand why would you need to change the url of the selected page, shouldn't they already be on that page anyways? its like saying stay on the same page looool its silly